# ERROR: type "json_param" does not exist at character 252

Tags: postgresql, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

Good day collegues.

I have very strange problem. I use docker-compose and part of my file looks like:

```
    version: "2.1"
services:   
  db:
    image: dr.mediascope.net/mediascope/wf/db:latest
    container_name: workflow_db_test
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dev
      - POSTGRES_DB=wf-db
    networks:
       wf_newfusion:
        aliases:
             - wf-db
    volumes:
      - /root/opt/databus_newfusion/workflow_newfusion/create-schema-docker.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/4-schema.sql
```

After starting docker i catch next err:

```
ERROR:  type "json_param" does not exist at character 252
```

Part of my SQL, it works fine from Idea:

```
-- separated schema which is dedicated for API
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS api CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA api;
ALTER SCHEMA api
OWNER TO wfweb_docker;

DROP TYPE IF EXISTS json_param;
CREATE TYPE json_param AS (id TEXT, label TEXT);

ALTER TYPE json_param
OWNER TO wfweb_docker;
```

.......

```
SET search_path = core, pg_catalog;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW api.v_scheme_param_set AS
  WITH cte AS (
      SELECT
        param_set_detail.param_set_id,
        json_agg(row_to_json(
                       ROW (param_set_detail.param_name :: TEXT, param_set_detail.param_val :: TEXT) :: json_param)) AS set_values
      FROM core.param_set_detail
      GROUP BY param_set_detail.param_set_id
  )
  SELECT
    s.scheme_id,
    cte.param_set_id,
    cte.set_values
  FROM core.param_set s
    JOIN cte ON s.param_set_id = cte.param_set_id
  ORDER BY cte.param_set_id DESC;
```

If i use Idea Ultimate and execute it, all work fine! No err message and other! If i use it inside "psql" or when docker starts it falls with err. Before this script three other was run, but all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you created the `json_param` type in the `api` schema. In that case you need to specify the schema name in your query when using that type, since you explicitly did *not* include that schema in your search path.

Also you don't need to include `pg_catalog` in your search path, as it's [*always* searched](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html).

Comment: so i need to execute smt like `SET search_path = core, pg_catalog,api`?

Comment: `SET search_path = core, api;` - or, change your cast `:: json_param)` to `:: api.json_param)`